# I met this problem when I trying to use onnx model in ML. NET

Tags: c#, ml.net, onnx

```
var context = new MLContext();
var emptyData = new List<FaceInput>();
var dataIn = context.Data.LoadFromEnumerable(emptyData);

var pipeline = context.Transforms.ResizeImages(resizing: ImageResizingEstimator.ResizingKind.Fill, outputColumnName: "data", imageWidth: ImageSettings.imageWidth, imageHeight: ImageSettings.imageHeight, inputColumnName: nameof(FaceInput.Image))
                 .Append(context.Transforms.ExtractPixels(outputColumnName: "data"))
                 .Append(context.Transforms.ApplyOnnxModel(modelFile: "./MLModel/model.onnx", outputColumnName: "classLabel", inputColumnName: "data"));

var model = pipeline.Fit(dataIn);

_predictionEngine = context.Model.CreatePredictionEngine<FaceInput, FacePredictions>(model);
```

[image]

I did research online, people say that is a bug from Microsoft. ML, but I tried many versions of it none of them work. (I am using v1.5.5 )
here are my onnx model properties.

[image]

The error occurs at :  var model = pipeline.Fit(dataIn);

It shows: System.InvalidOperationException: 'Input shape mismatch: Input 'data' has shape 1,3,224,224, but input data is of length 521667.'

Could you please help me with it?? Thank you very much!

Comment: please post error message as text rather than as image

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mcve].  It's not clear how to reproduce this issue from the question you've posted.